# Automated Testing of Tableau Reports

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, tableau-api

I have a Tableau report with several dropdowns lists. I want to look at particular dropdowns and verify if list values I am seeing is what I want to see. 
  Is there a way to automate testing on this part of the report? If so, please give me some pointers. I am pretty new to Tableau and I feel doing manual testing on a dropdown with several hundred values is exhausting. Please suggest possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you post some sample html? What errors are you running into? It sounds like you need to do more research to figure out what you need.

Comment: If you are using Tableau Server and want to test end to end via a browser, or emulated browser, then look at geb http://www.gebish.org

Answer (score 0):

Automated testing is not really supported by Tableau and can be quite difficult to implement on your own. There are commercial solutions for this at kinesis-ci.com. They can automate functional testing and integrate with Jenkins or other CI tools.