# Automatically test the data of the monthly generated Tableau report(s)

Tags: tableau-api

We generate Tableau reports frequently.

Is there a way to test the report generation in a CI (automated) fashion? Of course the tests focus on the data. A few hints would really help. The hints via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431816/automated-testing-of-tableau-reports) do not really help.

A normal process could be: start with filling a test database. The preparation and generation of the report is done. I guess the report must be published in a test environment.

How to test the result: via e.g. Cypress (on the website) or RobotFramework (on PDF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option we looked at was to generate a csv instead of rendering in the browser. The csv was much easier to parse through than trying to hack the AJAX in the browser. We abandoned the effort because it ended up not yielding us the benefits we hoped.